# Toolbar Overflow button onClick startactivity

Tags: android, android-actionbar, toolbar, android-toolbar

How can I start new activity on click of the Android toolbar's overflow button click. I don't want the dropdown to appear since I only have one item, rather directly change the activity.

Comment: where is your  code? Search on _google_ before asked

Comment: I did search on google, and what kind of code. I just want to know if its possible to do something like this. 

Here is some code:
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.hideOverflowMenu();
        toolbar.setLogo(R.drawable.logo);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line in your **menu_item.xml** file:

```
app:showAsAction="always"
```

**menu_item.xml:**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_github"
        android:title="@string/title_github"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_github"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

Comment: you da man. Thanks for this great tip/help! 

(I can accept the answer in 8 minutes :/ - please wait)